# create array instead of if...else in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a problem with this simple sidebar gadget I'm going to develop on converting values (mostly are inside javascript). Right now my code works as it is but with so much line of codes (2000+ lines) of similar code over and over again, which would be a horror of going to debug and change some code in the future.

So I'm trying to do array instead to reduce the line of codes, but when I do, I can't get it to work. Here's a sample of my work

```
function globVar() 
{

    var AIC = 4.11;  //random value
    var BIC = 3.42; 
    var CIC = 58.17;
    var DID = 441.16;
}

function doCalc() {
    globVar();
    var cellX = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var cellY = document.getElementById("sel2").value;

    if (cellX == "REC" && cellY == "AIC") {     
        var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;            
        var y = x * AIC;
        var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("value2").value = y2;
    }

    if (cellX == "REC" && cellY == "BIC") {
        var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;            
        var y = x * BIC);
        var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("value2").value = y2;
    }

    if (cellX == "REC" && cellY == "CIC") {
        var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;            
        var y = x * (1 / CIC);
        var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("value2").value = y2;
    }
}
```

this code work but to do this over 50 variables kinda too long to be used with if else, so I tried to use array.. with code below

```
globvar();
var cellX = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
var cellY = document.getElementById("sel2").value;

var unit1 = ["AIC", "BIC"];
var unit100 = ["CIC","DID"];

if (cellX == "REC") {
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        arrUnit = unit1[i];

        if (cellY == arrUnit) {
            var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;            
            var y = x * (1 / arrUnit);
            var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("value2").value = y2;

        }
    }

    for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {

        arrUnit = unit100[j];

        if (cellY == arrUnit) {
            var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;            
            var y = x * (1 / arrUnit);
            var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("value2").value = y2;
        }
    }
}
```

tried that but didn't work, get value 'Nan' instead so I must have been wrong somewhere or completely. Can someone point me where did I do wrong and explain why I'm wrong? I'm not very good with array.

Comment: Just a typo in the post: `var y = x * BIC);`? `NaN` usually occurs when you're trying to calculate with a mix of strings and numbers, notice, that the values of the input elements are strings.

Comment: ah, I see. No wonder I can't get the value from globVar() at all, always resulted in NaN. So what should I do to get the value from it using array?

Comment: I've no idea, since in your code you're actually doing for example: `var y = x * (1 / 'AIC');`, and I don't know, what have you entered to `#value1`.

Comment: #value1 (just numbers) is entered by user and the script will automatically calculate and show the result in #value2.

Comment: But you can't divide with `"AIC"`, can you? It looks like you need to enter strings, and store numbers to the array, or use an object like `{AIC: 4.11, BIC: 3.42, ...}`.

Comment: I am not sure how does even your if-else code works. You have defined AIC, BIC etc inside the function they don't have global scope.

Comment: @aSharma I just put random numbers there so shorten it. Actual value came from another function pulled from excel datasheet. When i use if...else, it work as I wanted it to be but it's too long to use it.

Comment: In your code, you have assigned string array ["AIC", "BIC"] to unit1 and unit100 variables. Then in for loop you take an element from this array in arrUnit and use it in the arithmetic formula x * (1 / arrUnit) But arrUnit is a string how is it supposed to divide 1? Hence you get NaN. You can try putting all values in a json object as suggested by @Teemu. e.g. values = {"AIC" : 4.11}. then use values[arrUnit] in the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: Calculation of numbers with decimals in pure javascript is a bad, really bad idea!**

[**Floating-point literals on developer.mozilla.org**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals)

You can use [**Math.js**](http://mathjs.org/) or any other math library which already operate with decimals correctly.

---

The thing is you looking for - called **"[Finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)"**

Your code could looks like:

```
var rates = { // here where your constants should be defined
    'AIC': 0,
    'BIC': 0,
    'CIC': 0,
};

var actions = {
    'REC': function (x, rate) {
        return x * (1 / rate);
    },
    'XEC': function (x, rate) {
        return x * rate;
    }
};


function doCalc() {
    globVar();
    var cellX = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var cellY = document.getElementById("sel2").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var y = actions[cellX](x, rates[cellY]);

    document.getElementById("value2").value = y.toFixed(2);
}
```

And here how resetRates should looks like:

```
function resetRates() {

        globVar();
        // To refresh rates with latest value

        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false; //false to hide while true to debug
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("//path/to/excelfiles/rates.xls");
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");

        rates['AIC'] = excel_sheet.Cells(3,7).Value;
        rates['BIC'] = excel_sheet.Cells(4,7).Value;
        rates['CIC'] = excel_sheet.Cells(5,7).Value;
        rates['DID'] = excel_sheet.Cells(6,7).Value;
        rates['EID'] = excel_sheet.Cells(7,7).Value;
        rates['FID'] = excel_sheet.Cells(8,7).Value;
        rates['GIE'] = excel_sheet.Cells(9,7).Value;
        rates['HIE'] = excel_sheet.Cells(10,7).Value;
        rates['IIE'] = excel_sheet.Cells(11,7).Value;


        excel.Quit();
}
```

Comment: oh, thanks. Unfortunately this is still a problem.. only reduce about 200 line of codes over 50 variables. I forgot to mention that my script only have two formula and it's been used over and over, hence why I want to use array to simplify it.

Comment: @flagstar, can you please provide full example of code. Because it is not really clear how to optimize it.

Comment: here's another sample. http://pastebin.com/SvvXmnhr I still shorten it since everything still the same, repeated line.

Comment: @Teemu, please check link, provided by author of the question in comments below.  pastebin.com/SvvXmnhr

Answer (score 0):

If your function is the same for all values (`y = x * <value>`) you can do something like this.

```
var v = [];
v['REC'] = [];

function globVar() 
{
    var rec = v['REC'];
    rec['AIC'] = 4.11;  //random value
    rec['BIC'] = 3.42; 
    rec['CIC'] = 1 / 58.17;
    rec['DID'] = 441.16;
}

globVar();

function doCalc() {
    var cellX = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var cellY = document.getElementById("sel2").value;

    var x = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var y = x * v[cellX][cellY];
    var y2 = y.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("value2").value = y2; 
}
```

Otherwise, you will need an array with functions too.